# Join shapefile to a raster created by interpolation (IDW)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, attribute-joins, interpolation

I want to join this raster to a shapefile; I created this raster by IDW, it is rainfall information for my country and the shapefile it is for all the townships. I want to know the exactly rainfall data for each municipality but I don't know how to merge these to files. I tried "raster to polygon" but it does not work, I also tried "build raster attribute table" but it did not work. It is even possible to do that? I mean, these two files do not match in any attribute besides the country. I was thinking to declassify the raster but I don't know...

Here are the images

[image: municipalities with rainfall info]

these are the layers

[image]

Comment: Hey, in ArcGis you can use the Zonal Statistics Tools to extract info from your raster (such as mean or maximum and minimum value) for each polygon representing a township in your shapefile. More info can be found here: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/how-zonal-statistics-works.htm

Comment: "Did not work" is not a useful problem statement. Please [Edit] the Question